# C# VS2010 Win7 64-bit iSeries Access ODBC Driver Communication link failure

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, odbc, ibm-midrange

I'm having a problem upgrading a c# app from WinXP to Win7 64 bit. The app queries data from our iSeries.  I've set up a 64 bit ODBC DSN, which works if I try from within MS Access.  But, when I try to establish a connection in the C# code, I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR [08S01] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=10022 - CWBCO1003 - Sockets error, function  returned 10022

My connection code is as follows:

```
cn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=as400data;UID=user;PWD=password;");
cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn);
cn.Open();
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what may be raising this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put this here in case someone else has this problem one day.

The resolution to this problem was to put the code under development directly on the C:\ drive of the development machine.  Typically, I keep my code out on a network drive, so that it gets backed up.  There's some kind of issue with doing that in Win7, however.